# FTP (ApacheCommons) ObjectInputStream throws EOFException

Tags: android, ftp, apache-commons, objectinputstream

Here is the code.

```
    Client.changeWorkingDirectory("./Users");
    Client.changeWorkingDirectory("Users");
    Client.changeWorkingDirectory(UsernameString);
    Client.changeWorkingDirectory("ActiveSells");
    Client.setBufferSize(1024*1024);
    Object earray[] = new Object[5];      //In my code earray is actually something
    Out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
    OOS = new ObjectOutputStream(Out);
    OOS.writeObject(earray);
    RetrievedItem = Out.toByteArray();         //RetrievedItem is a ByteArray
    System.out.println(RetrievedItem.length);  //This tells me 401257
    OOS.flush();
    OOS.close();
    OOS = new ObjectOutputStream(Client.storeFileStream(((String)array[0]).toString()));
    OOS.writeObject(RetrievedItem);
    OOS.flush();
    OOS.close();
    Client.completePendingCommand();
    System.out.println("GetResponse");
    String response = Client.getReplyString();
    System.out.println(response);
    InputStream FIS = Client.retrieveFileStream(((String)array[0]).toString());
    String response2 = Client.getReplyString();
    System.out.println(response2);  //This tells me 390.7kb to download
    OIS = new ObjectInputStream(FIS);
    RetrievedItem = ((byte[])OIS.readObject());  //Gives me EOF
    System.out.println(RetrievedItem.toString());  //From here down the code is skipped
    In = new ByteArrayInputStream(RetrievedItem);  
    OIS = new ObjectInputStream(In);
    Object retrievedfinally = OIS.readObject();
    System.out.println(retrievedfinally);
    In.close();


    return FragMan;
```

The size of the file on the server is 391kb. I'm not sure if the problem is in uploading the object or download the object. Anyone have any suggestions as to why this is malfunctioning?

Here is the error

```
12-07 01:12:19.581: W/System.err(20719): java.io.EOFException
12-07 01:12:19.589: W/System.err(20719):    at    libcore.io.Streams.readFully(Streams.java:83)
12-07 01:12:19.589: W/System.err(20719):    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:120)
12-07 01:12:19.589: W/System.err(20719):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1473)
12-07 01:12:19.589: W/System.err(20719):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:785)
12-07 01:12:19.589: W/System.err(20719):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2006)
12-07 01:12:19.589: W/System.err(20719):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1963)
12-07 01:12:19.589: W/System.err(20719):    at com.blablaba.NetAsyncTask.NewSellItemUpload(NetAsyncTask.java:309)
12-07 01:12:19.589: W/System.err(20719):    at com.blablabla.NetAsyncTask.UploadFile(NetAsyncTask.java:203)
12-07 01:12:19.589: W/System.err(20719):    at com.blablabla.NetAsyncTask.doInBackground(NetAsyncTask.java:112)
12-07 01:12:19.589: W/System.err(20719):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
12-07 01:12:19.589: W/System.err(20719):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
12-07 01:12:19.589: W/System.err(20719):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
12-07 01:12:19.589: W/System.err(20719):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
12-07 01:12:19.589: W/System.err(20719):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
12-07 01:12:19.589: W/System.err(20719):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Answer (score 0):

So apparently this is a problem that can't be solved. The object I was trying to upload was an array of objects, and the last object is an image. It seems that it's a glitch within Apache commons that it doesn't upload the last bit of an image, thereby corrupting it. I have switched to ftp4j and it works.